# Как изменить имя ПК в графе "Владелец" в подключениях к базам в аспе

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, windows-7

Доброго времени суток, граждане StackOverflow=)
Изменил имя компа на то же самое, только без черточки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В следствии чего при попытке работы со схемами данных получаю следующее

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Гугл не подсказал как обновить информацию в поле "Владелец", а прямо там не редактируется. Прошу вашей помощи

Answer (score 1):

Вариант **А**:
Удалить все ссылки на базы в обозревателе и создать их заново

Вариант **B**:
Удалить все ссылки на базы в обозревателе и по-человечески прописать `connectionString` в *Web.config*